# Run different versions of Pandas in different module of the same programm

Tags: python, module, pandas

Is it possible to run different versions of **Pandas** in different **module** of the same program?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: i have some old libraries (not so old!) written for pandas 0.13.1 and they don't work with pandas 0.14. I would like to use them without change

Comment: this sounds like a recipe for disaster -- can't you update the old libraries? the api changes for pandas should be pretty minimal from version to version.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is it due to api changes or bugs in the respective libraries?

Comment: Maybe I have some problem with update pandas in my pc.. I try my libraries in another python installation and they works on 0.14.1! Thanks a lot to all for answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do this, then, in general, to load packages from specific locations:

```
import imp
pandas13 = imp.load_module("pandas13",
                           *imp.find_module("pandas", ["/path/to/pandas13/parent/"]))
pandas14 = imp.load_module("pandas14",
                           *imp.find_module("pandas", ["/path/to/pandas14/parent/"]))
```

i.e. pandas 0.13 will be in `/path/to/pandas13/parent/pandas/`

Then any successive call to `import pandas14` will return `pandas14`, and `import pandas13` will return `pandas13`. If this doesn't work, it will be because pandas doesn't use relative namespacing (I think it does), in which case you would need to change all the imports in the package to be relative.

There is no way to do this using absolute in-package imports.

Although, really, I can't imagine why you'd need to do this.